# Error en la instalacion de Apache Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

Estoy realizando la instalación del apache xampp normalmente pero llega un monento en el que sale una ventana con el siguiente error:

There has been an error
Unknow error unpacking file C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll
the application will exit now.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Podrían decirme como se soluciona este problema?

Comment: Intenta instalar XAMPP en un una particion o carpeta diferente. Prueba tambien a descargarlo de nuevo.

Comment: No ha funcionado, ni instalarlo en una partición diferente, ni descargarlo nuevamente

Comment: ¿Algún antivirus activo que pueda estar entorpeciendo de forma silenciosa?

Comment: Uso el antivirus solo cuando deseo hacer un escaneo completo de mi computador cada cierto tiempo, por lo que la mayoría del tiempo tengo mi antivirus desactivado y tomo las precauciones necesarias para que mi computadora no se infecte de virus, Osea, el **Sentido Común** es mi mejor antivirus